# How do you alter the ODBC connection string for existing MS-ACCESS pass-through queries in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pass-through

I have a number of pass-through queries setup in a MS-Access database with pre-defined ODBC connection strings. The problem is the database can link to one of two MySQL databases. The user selects the db on starting the database and the system dynamically links the appropriate tables via VBA (this works fine) However I then need to alter the ODBC Connection strings in the existing queries to match the selected db. I therefore needa VBA function to loop through all the existing pass-through queries setting the ODBC connection string propertiy to the new connection string. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the queries collection:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef

For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    If qdf.Type = dbQSQLPassThrough Then
        qdf.Connect = NewConnect
    End If
Next
```

You could also examine the Connect string with `InStr(qdf.Connect)` to test for the existence of the required database name.

Comment: Thanks, although this does alter the connection string which is great, it sets the connection for non-pass-through queries, hence making all the queries pass-through. I need to restrict the alterations to just the pass-through queries. However you have provided a good starting point.

Comment: @Acoats I have added a further note.

Comment: Solved it by adding a check for **qdf.Connect <> ""** which restricts it to only pass-through queries.

Comment: Yes, replacing 
    **If qdf.Type = dbQSQLPassThrough**
with
    **If qdf.Connect <> ""**
did the trick for me.